# Display doesnt startup after lock

Tags: brightness, lock-screen

Whenever I'm not using the laptop I turn the screen off using the Fn+F2 button which eventually reduces the screen brightness to 0. By default the lock screen should start in 10 minutes, after 10 minutes, when I hit Fn+F3 to increase the brightness, the display doesn't start and I have to forcibly shut it down and restart. How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Don't reduce the brightness.
Instead try to hibernate your laptop when not in use.
Close the flap and when u open it,laptop will automatically wake up.

Comment: I want to laptop working, I have active processes going on

Comment: While in hibernation,processes are continued.But if you have a low battery then they might be closed.Give it a try.Try copying or downloading something and hibernate.See if the task completes.